# SSH error ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer after setting tcp_keepalive_time to 0

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, linux-kernel

I was trying to do some modification on tcp_keepalive_time, but accidentally changed the value to 0. Resulting, not able to login or do ssh into the linux system . On doing a ssh to the system i am getting

> $ ssh prxxxd@lxxxxx.xxxxx.com
>
> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

How can I, ssh back to this system ?

Comment: Try with ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=50 user@box.example.com

Comment: Same question on [su]: https://superuser.com/q/1214574/54530